# Jupyter notebook can't show the regression summary

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I just met a problem when I did a regression analysis between two columns of data.

```
In [19]: import statsmodels.api as sm

         xdat = rets['EUROSTOXX']
         ydat = rets['VSTOXX']
         model = sm.OLS(ydat, xdat)
         model

Out[19]: <statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS at 0x4793da0>
```

How can I get a model summary result rather than a storage address? Thanks!!!

Comment: Here you have some examples, [statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html)

Comment: I still can't solve the problem... Can you explain to me concretely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to fit your model,

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

ydat = rets["VSTOXX"]
xdat = rets["EUROSTOXX"]
xdat = sm.add_constant(xdat)

model = sm.OLS(ydat, xdat)
results = model.fit()
```

Then you can print the coefficient result,

```
print(results.t_test([1, 0]))
```

and the summary results,

```
print(results.summary())
```

Comment: I forgot `xdat = sm.add_constant(xdat)`, try again. That works for me.

Comment: @Hot I'm glad to hear that. Don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add method parenthesis after model
as `model.summary()`

It works for me as

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

ydat = rets["VSTOXX"]
xdat = rets["EUROSTOXX"]

# Adding constant for Intercept
xdat = sm.add_constant(xdat)

model = sm.OLS(ydat, xdat)
results = model.fit()
```

Then, simply as

```
model.summary()
```

You can also get R^2 and Adj.R^2 directly using

```
print(model.rsquared)
print(model.rsquared_adj)
```

More at : [statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults)

Answer (score 0):

For better presentation or result display you can use

```
xdat = sm.add_constant(xdat)
model = sm.OLS(ydat,xdat).fit()

print(model.summary())
```